# How to exit a layout and keep methods running?

Tags: android, android-layout, methods, android-activity, exit

I have Act1 and Act2. On Act1 there is a button that opens Act2 that sets a new layout. 
How can I exit the layout but keep the methods running?
My problem is not how to program the parallelism, my problem is how to avoid the whole activity to shut when back button is pressed ( I already use the onPressedButton() to identify when it is pressed ) but I don't know how to get rid of the layout and keep only the methods of the Act2 running. Finish() will kill everything.
Thank you.

EDIT: I have no sample code because what I have right now is two separated activities that I have not yet managed to link.

I have a program that has images scrolling in the main screen and you can click them with your fingers, normal way. I am trying to implement a new way of interacting with the program using an headset that reads brain waves and it is able to recognize when eye blinks are performed. So I am trying to adapt the program so that disabled people will be able to use it only by blinking. Therefore, I need to have the regular program to run and a parallel process that is constantly reading messages from the headset. It is required that both blink and touch functionality work at the same time, i.e, that the touch functionality remains available either you have the headset on or off.

Comment: What methods do you want running?

Comment: I want to be able to keep Act2 methods.

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense in the context of android development. Could you show what you are trying to accomplish with some sample code? Whatever you're doing, you're probably going about it the wrong way, and you'll run into other problems along the way.

Comment: I edited the post above and explained my problem. Maybe it's clear now what I need to do. Sorry if I am not clear enough, I am really confused right now.

Comment: what do you mean "method running" ?

Comment: The methods that exchange and decode the messages from the headset are on Act2. There is the need of having a graphical layout so that people can choose through a button to connect the headset (and exchange information) and those methods need to be running permanently.

Comment: Service are best option to run the particular method continuously.Apart fro this you can use Broadcastreciever,timers,hadlers but firstly your requirement must be clear about what you want to achieve and which option would be best for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement your methods to run as a service and it will be independent on the activity.

Comment: But isn't Service only for short background processes? What I really want to program is more like a thread (an Executor or an AsyncTask) that uses the output of the methods on Act2 and sets them through Shared Preferences to be read by Act1 : /

Comment: Then create AsyncTask instead of activity.